# NameError in LineItemsController#create (uninitialized constant LineItem::CaterOrderOptions)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm following along in a book called Agile Web Development with Rails 5. For the most part, I'm using different file names, so I can force myself to not simply copy/paste code. Everything was going well up until I tried implementing a cart and line_items.

As the title states, I'm getting an error stating "NameError in LineItemsController#create (uninitialized constant LineItem::CaterOrderOptions)". My **create** class in the **line_items_controller** seems to **causing issues**. I don't quite understand this error, please let me know if you have any suggestions! Would be appreciated!

I tried following the books syntax exactly for my line_items_controller, don't really know what I'm screwing up. Book's format:

```
Product.find(params[:product_id]) 
@line_item = @cart.line_items.build(product: product) 

respond_to do |format| 
if @line_item.save 
  format.html { redirect_to @line_item.cart"
```

My line_items controller w/ create class

```
class LineItemsController < ApplicationController
  include CurrentCart

  before_action :set_cart, only: [:create]

before_action :set_line_item, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]


# GET /line_items

 # GET /line_items.json

 def index

 @line_items = LineItem.all

 end



# GET /line_items/1

 # GET /line_items/1.json

def show

end


 # GET /line_items/new

 def new

 @line_item = LineItem.new

end


 # GET /line_items/1/edit

def edit

end


# POST /line_items

# POST /line_items.json

def create

 cater_order_options = CaterOrderOption.find(params[:cater_order_options_id])     # SOURCE OF PROBLEMS# SOURCE OF PROBLEMS# SOURCE OF PROBLEMS# SOURCE OF PROBLEMS# SOURCE OF PROBLEMS# SOURCE OF PROBLEMS# SOURCE OF PROBLEMS# SOURCE OF PROBLEMS


@line_item = @cart.line_items.build(cater_order_options: cater_order_options) # SOURCE OF PROBLEMS# SOURCE OF PROBLEMS# SOURCE OF PROBLEMS# SOURCE OF PROBLEMS# SOURCE OF PROBLEMS# SOURCE OF PROBLEMS# SOURCE OF PROBLEMS# SOURCE OF PROBLEMS# SOURCE OF PROBLEMS


respond_to do |format|
  if @line_item.save
    format.html { redirect_to @line_item.cart, 
    notice: 'Line item was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @line_item }
  else
    format.html { render :new }
    format.json { render json: @line_item.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end

end
```

Button for adding to cart

```
<% @CateringMenu.each do |f| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= f.cateringOptions %></td>
    <td><%= f.CaterDesc %></td>
    <td><%= f.sideOptions %></td>
    <td><%= f.sideDesc %></td>
    <td><%= number_to_currency(f.price) %></td>
    <td><%= button_to 'Add to Cart', line_items_path(cater_order_options_id: f) %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

Line_item model

```
class LineItem < ApplicationRecord
belongs_to :cater_order_options
belongs_to :cart
end
```

cater_order_options model

```
class CaterOrderOption < ApplicationRecord
has_many :line_items
before_destroy :ensure_not_referenced_by_any_line_item

private
    #Check to ensure no line items are referencing this product
    def ensure_not_referenced_by_any_line_item
        unless line_items.empty?
            errors.add(:base, 'Line Items Present')
            #if aborted row is not destroyed
            throw :abort
        end   
    end
 end
```

cater_order_options controller - some of it(to show variable names)

```
before_action :set_cater_order_option, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

def index
  @cater_order_options = CaterOrderOption.all
end

def new
  @cater_order_option = CaterOrderOption.new
end

private

def set_cater_order_option
  @cater_order_option = CaterOrderOption.find(params[:id])
end


def cater_order_option_params
  params.require(:cater_order_option).permit(:cateringOptions, :CaterDesc, :sideOptions, :sideDesc, :price)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

`belongs_to` always takes a singular, so change this line to refer to `cater_order_option` instead of `cater_order_options`

```
belongs_to :cater_order_option
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I actually tried changing that a bit earlier, and did so again. It prompts me with a new error, "ActiveModel::UnknownAttributeError in LineItemsController#create". I thought this might mean that having no (s) at the end was incorrect, but I guess that's not the issue? Any idea what might be causing this?

Comment: I guess it seems like it's not liking my create class and those first two lines still. Before it seemed to at least recognized the 'cater_order_options_ attribute.

Comment: What unknown attribute are you getting

Comment: It was saying "unknown attribute 'cater_order_options' for LineItem".  I then tried changing that attribute to match the singular "cater_order_option" like in the line_item model, so I changed it to "cater_order_option: cater_order_options" ("cater_order_options" being the same variable seen in my code). After doing that I got an error saying "can't write unknown attribute 'cater_order_option_id'. The attribute I need is "cater_order_options_id", so I guess having no (s) is the wrong move? It's fetching the cater_order_options_id in my log just fine.

Comment: I can only fix this error by having an attribute from the line_items db schema in there, and doing that only leads to success because it prompts a jquery error message saying "Cater order option must exist". In the book, the db has no 'product' in line_items db schema, yet it still successfully builds the newly selected line_item using "line_items.build(product: product)".